# How to fetch numeric values from paragraph tag?

Tags: jquery

I am having N number of paragraph tag. Each paragraph tag will have some numbers. I want to fetch these numbers and store it in a variables. For Example:

```
<p id="id_1">1</p>
<p id="id_2">2</p>
<p id="id_3">3</p>
<p id="id_2">4</p>
and so on...
```

These numbers are fetch from the input text field and stored inside paragraph tag. 
I want to store these numbers in a variable called numbers.

```
<input type="text" id="numerics" />      //using #numeric.val(); I stored the numbers in paragraph
```

And the js is:

```
var numbers = parseInt($("#id_'+$('#numeric').val()+'").text().trim(), 10);
```

But it doesn't works. Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misused the quotes.

Use

```
var number = parseInt($('#id_'+$('#numeric').val()).text().trim(), 10);
```

To make an array from all id_* paragraphs, do

```
var numbers = $('p[id^="id_"]').map(function(){
     return parseInt($(this).text().trim(), 10)
}).get();
```

Result : `[1, 2, 3, 4]`

Note that the index starts at 0 instead of 1, so if you want to find the number using your input, you need to do

```
var number = numbers[parseInt($('#numeric').val().trim(),10)-1];
```

Comment: Is that possible to store those numbers in arrays?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var numbers = parseInt($("#id_"+$('#numeric').val()).text().trim(), 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how you want to store them, in an array or just summarize them?

here's an example of both.

http://jsfiddle.net/z4HL4/1/

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    var numbers = [];
    var sum = 0;

    $("p").each(function(i){

        // get the number as int
        var idNumber = parseInt($(this).attr("id").replace("id_", ""), 10);

        // save in array
        numbers[i] = idNumber;

        // add to our sum
        sum += idNumber;
    });

    // as array
    console.log(numbers);

    // as sum
    console.log(sum);
});
```